# How to fetch data once in Next.js 13 and pass it as a props

Tags: next.js, axios, server-side-rendering, next.js13, app-router

I'm having an optimization issue when I want to display dynamic title for the page and dynamic UI.

In my case **I'm sending the same request 2 times** - 1st time to generate metadata and 2nd time in order to pass it as a props to my UI component.

Previously, in Next.js with pages, I would solve it using getServerSideProps, but as long as this component anyways rendering on server, I didn't find any function; solution which would allow me to pass data from the server as a props for my functions (as it was when you were using pages router)

**I use axios** for querying data, initially I wanted to use **RTK Query (and this problem would be solved because of caching)**, but for now RTK Query doesn't support **React Server Components**

My `component.ts` file

```
import MyComponent from '@/components/screens/screen/component';

import { getDataSSR } from '@/components/screens/screen/api/screen.ssr';
import { IData } from '@/components/screens/screen/types/data.type';

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const data = await getDataSSR({ id: Number(params?.id)}) as IData;

  return {
    title: `${data?.data?.details?.userProfile?.fullName}`,
  };
}

const ComponentPage = async ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const data = await getDataSSR({ id: Number(params?.id) }) as IData;
  
  return <MyComponent id={params.id} data={data} />;
};

export default ComponentPage;
```

I tried to ask chat-gpt 4 about this, but unfortunately, he didn't provide me any valuable and working solution.

Comment: Correct me if I didn't understood, ***You want to call a API Server-side, get data from it, pass it to client as prop & also generate metadata using it  ?***

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

> I'm sending the same request 2 times - 1st time to generate metadata and 2nd time in order to pass it as a props to my UI component.

**Solution :**

- NextJS does caching when you use fetch, but when using external libraries you don't know its internal cache behavior.
- You can use `cache` function provided by React, wrap your API Call function in cache function. *(Read the [1](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#example)st link given below)*

**Here's a small code I made :**

**Folder Structure :**

```
projectName
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── api
│       ├── comp
│       │   └── User.js
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── layout.js
│       └── user
│           ├── page.js
│           └── [id]
│               └── page.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

**Explaination :**

- I have made a page called Users, which shows all users.
- I have made a component which takes data, & makes hyerlinks to open a specific user page (click on Terry's link, opens Terry's details page).
- I have made a user details page, which calls a details api to show user details. This page has, `generateMetadata` which calls a `GetUserData` API & the page function also calls `GetUserData` API .
- `[id]\page.js` is user details page
- `comp` is component folder

**All Users Page**  `projectName\src\app\user\page.js` :

```
import axios from "axios";
import User from "../comp/User";

async function GetAllUsers() {
    let { data } = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/users')

    return data

    // CHANGE ABOVE CODE ACCORDING TO AXIOS
}
// ABOVE API SIMULATES SERVER-SIDE DATA FETCHING


export default async function Page() {

    let UserData = await GetAllUsers();
    // console.log("Data KEYS from API on Serverside : ", Object.keys(UserData));
    // THIS LOG WILL BE IN TERMINAL AS THIS PAGE IS SERVER-SIDE RENDERED
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Users Page</h1>
            <User Data={UserData} />
            {/* COMPONENT */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**User Component :** `projectName\src\app\comp\User.js`

```
'use client'
import Link from 'next/link'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const User = ({ Data }) => {
    // console.log("Data.users", Data.users);
    // VISBILE IN BROWSER

    const [UserData, SetUserData] = useState(Data.users)
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Client Component Gets data from Server as props, renders it below.</h3>
            <ol>
                {
                    UserData.map((u, i) => (
                        <li key={i}>
                            <Link href={`/user/` + u.id} >{u.firstName}</Link>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ol>
        </div>
    )
}
export default User;
```

**User details page** `projectName\src\app\user\[id]\page.js` :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { cache } from 'react'

const GetUserData = cache(async (ID) => {
    // console.log(ID);
    console.log("GetUserData HIT (cache) : ", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    let { data } = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/user/' + ID)
    return data

})


// WITHOUT ANY CACHING , THIS RUNS TWICE
// UNCOMMENT BELOW CODE TO RUN & COMMENT ABOVE CODE

// const GetUserData = async (ID) => {
//     // console.log(ID);
//    console.log("GetUserData HIT : ", new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

//     let { data } = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/user/' + ID)
//     return data
//     // CHANGE ABOVE CODE ACCORDING TO AXIOS
// }

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {

    let UserData = await GetUserData(params.id)
    return {
        title: UserData.firstName + " " + params.id,
    };
}

const UserDetailsPage = async ({ params }) => {
    let UserData = await GetUserData(params.id)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>UserDetailsPage </h1>
            <p>ID:{params.id} </p>
            <p>FirstName : {UserData.firstName}</p>
            <p>LastName : {UserData.lastName}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserDetailsPage
```

**Output :**

- Goto `http://localhost:3000/user` you will see all users fetch from api.
- Now click on anyone, it will take you to UserDetailsPage, `http://localhost:3000/user/id_of_user` see this page has Title + User ID (made using generateMetadata function) this page has api 2 calls 1st uses cache & 2nd doesn't.
- you will see in terminal it `cache` wrapped api call executes only once. But if you comment this  `cache` wrapped api call & uncomment the below api call you see it fires twice.

***Please Read :***

- **Example which shows use of cache function :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#example
- **Caching Data :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#caching-data
- **Fetching data on the Server with third-party libraries :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries
- **Data Fetching, Caching, and Revalidating :**  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
- **Dynamic Routes :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment(i will update answer if required)***

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your solution and effort :)